# How can I add a character space after the tags function in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using this code

```
<span class="tab-text-subheader">
    <? echo ($rrow['tags']) ? $rrow['tags'] : "-"; ?>
</span>
```

to pull tags and list them, at the moment it shows up like this

```
Tags: tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4
```

but I would like there to be a space after the comas such as

```
Tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4
```

I tried a few different solutions but I am not expert with code.Thanks

Comment: **Don't** use `<? echo`, **use** `<?php echo` instead.

Comment: Or just use `<?=`

Answer (score 0):

Just use string replace function and replace `,` with `,` (comma with space)

`<span class="tab-text-subheader"><? echo ($rrow['tags']) ? str_replace(',', '&nbsp;', $rrow['tags']); : "-"; ?></span>`

I hope this work for you